# how to do 'exec' definition inside class Python

Tags: python, class

guys. I started to study classes recently and while playing around was trying to do something like this :

```
from functools import partial

class test():
    def __init__(self):
         exec('def foo(self, number): x = number; return x') 

    def printingX(self):
         command = partial(self.foo, 1)
         print command
a = test() 
a.printingX()
```

It's of course giving an error, but my question is : Is it possible to store method inside '**init**' and then to call it in other methods later? If it's possible, is it a good practice to do or bad?

Comment: It's terrible practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but generally, don't.

I would say [be careful with exec](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/). But other than that, there is not much stopping you really from doing this

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     def __init__(self):
...         exec('MyClass.foo = lambda self, x: x*x')
...
>>> c = MyClass()
>>> c.foo(3)
9
```

ALTHOUGH, my suggestion is that you do not do this since it is highly impractical and there is no convention for it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to store method inside 'init'

Depends on what you mean by "storing" ? But if you meant "define", yes, you can define functions (nb: `def` always defines a function, it only becomes a "method" when it's looked up on a class or instance). And you don't need `exec` for this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        def bar(baaz):
            print("in bar: {}".format(baaz))
        bar(arg)
```

> and then to call it in other methods later?

If you want to make it a method, you can add it either to the instance:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
        def bar(self):
            print("in self.bar: {}".format(self.arg))
        self.bar = bar.__get__(self, type(self))
```

or to the class (which means it will be overwritten every time you instanciate the class):

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
        def bar(self):
            print("in self.bar: {}".format(self.arg))
        type(self).bar = bar
```

> If it's possible, is it a good practice to do or bad?

Well, as written above, it's absurd, confusing and inefficient, so I fail to see how this could qualify as good practice.  And doing it with `exec` is just a complete WTF.

If the goal is to somehow parameterize a given method for each instance (based on a condition or whatnot), you can just pass the function - or any callable FWIW - as an argument (python functions are objects like any other):

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, arg, strategy):
        self.arg = arg
        # we may not want to expose it
        # as part of the class API
        self._strategy = strategy

    def bar(self, value):
        return self._strategy(self, value)


def my_strategy(foo, value):
    return foo.arg * value

f = Foo(42, my_strategy)
f.bar(2)
```

FWIW, this is known as the "strategy" design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can do exactly what you wanted, but you must use the globals and locals parameters of `exec` to limit the risk of exec-ing a dangerous string and getting the function definition:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        funcs = {}
        exec('def foo(self, number): x = number; return x',
             {'__builtins__':{}}, funcs)
        for func in funcs:
            if not hasattr(self.__class__, func):
                setattr(self.__class__, func, funcs[func])
```

This code explicitely adds the compiled function into the class on creation of first object.

Demo:

```
>>> test.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', '__init__': <function test.__init__ at 0x000001E5C5F27EA0>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'test' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'test' objects>, '__doc__': None})
>>> t = test()
>>> test.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', '__init__': <function test.__init__ at 0x000001E5C5F27EA0>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'test' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'test' objects>, '__doc__': None, 'foo': <function foo at 0x000001E5C5F27F28>})
>>> t.foo(12)
12
```

This clearly shows that the `foo` method has been added to the class when creating its first instance.

But... **please don't!!!**. This code only shows that Python is kind enough to allow run time modification of classes, and that a method if just a class attribute that happens to be a function. Ok, the string passed to exec is controlled so there is no security problem here, but `exec` and `eval` should be avoided when possible.

And unless you have a real need for code like that, it leads to a hard to understand class when readability should be the first thought for a Python programmer.

So to answer your second question it is really a terrible practice. Never say that I advised to use it.